# How can I save data I have scraped in a loop into my csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, range

I am trying to scrape the website for each teams roster and then export it into a csv file. The code is able to scrape the data but it only saves the final teams data (New York Rangers) into the csv. Just wondering how I can save all the scraped data from the loop?

```
import pandas as pd
import time

team = ['Toronto Maple Leafs', 'Montreal Canadiens', 'Boston Bruins', 'Chicago Blackhawks', 'Detroit Red Wings', 'New York Rangers']
code = ['TOR', 'MTL', 'BOS', 'CHI', 'DET', 'NYR']

for i in range(0, len(code)):
    codes = code[i]
    teams = team[i]
    df = pd.read_html(f'https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/{codes}/#roster', match='Roster')
    df = df[0]
    df = df[['Player']]
    df = df.assign(Team=[teams]*len(df), Rating=['99']*len(df))
    print(df)
    time.sleep(5)
    df.to_csv('Players.csv')
print("Saved!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `mode='a'` to append all the new data to the existing data in the loop.

```
df.to_csv('Players.csv', mode='a')
```

doc: [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv)

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest another method. Instead of having to write to file after each iterations, just store in a list, the write the full dataframe 1 time. I'd also consider iterating through a dictionary as opposed to an i/index value of a list.

```
import pandas as pd
import time


team_dict = {
 'TOR': 'Toronto Maple Leafs',
 'MTL': 'Montreal Canadiens',
 'BOS': 'Boston Bruins',
 'CHI': 'Chicago Blackhawks',
 'DET': 'Detroit Red Wings',
 'NYR': 'New York Rangers'}

dfs = []
for codes, teams in team_dict.items():
    df = pd.read_html(f'https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/{codes}/#roster', match='Roster')
    df = df[0]
    df = df[['Player']]
    df[['Team', 'Rating']] = teams, '99'
    print(df)
    time.sleep(5)

final_df = pd.concat(dfs)
final_df.to_csv('Players.csv')
print("Saved!")
```